# Convert a decision tree to a table

Tags: machine-learning, datatable, scikit-learn, decision-tree, converters

I'm looking for a way to convert a decision tree trained using scikit sklearn into a decision table.

I would like to know how to parse the decision tree structure to find the decisions made at each step.
Then I would like ideas on how to structure this table.
Do you know a way or have a idea to do it?

Comment: See [this example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code to convert a decision tree into a "python" code. You can easily adapt it to make a table.

All you need to do is create a global variable that is a table that is the size of the number of leaves times the number of features (or feature categories) and fill it recursively

```py
    def tree_to_code(tree, feature_names, classes_names):
        tree_ = tree.tree_
        feature_name = [
            feature_names[i] if i != _tree.TREE_UNDEFINED else "undefined!"
            for i in tree_.feature
        ]
    
        print( "def tree(" + ", ".join(feature_names) + "):" )
    
        def recurse(node, depth):
            indent = "  " * depth
            if tree_.feature[node] != _tree.TREE_UNDEFINED:
                name = feature_name[node]
                threshold = tree_.threshold[node]
    
                print( indent + "if " + name + " <= " +  str(threshold)+ ":" )
                recurse(tree_.children_left[node], depth + 1)
                print( indent + "else:  # if " + name + "<=" +  str(threshold) )
                recurse(tree_.children_right[node], depth + 1)
            else:
                impurity = tree.tree_.impurity[node]
                dico, label = cast_value_to_dico( tree_.value[node], classes_names )
    
                print( indent + "# impurity=" + str(impurity) + " count_max=" + str(dico[label]) )
                print( indent + "return " + str(label) )
    
        recurse(0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on the [other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53400587/3087542). The following traverses the tree in the same way but generates a pandas dataframe as an output.

```py
import sklearn
import pandas as pd

def tree_to_df(reg_tree, feature_names):
    tree_ = reg_tree.tree_
    feature_name = [
        feature_names[i] if i != sklearn.tree._tree.TREE_UNDEFINED else "undefined!"
        for i in tree_.feature
    ]
    
    def recurse(node, row, ret):
        if tree_.feature[node] != sklearn.tree._tree.TREE_UNDEFINED:
            name = feature_name[node]
            threshold = tree_.threshold[node]
            # Add rule to row and search left branch
            row[-1].append(name + " <= " +  str(threshold))
            recurse(tree_.children_left[node], row, ret)
            # Add rule to row and search right branch
            row[-1].append(name + " > " +  str(threshold))
            recurse(tree_.children_right[node], row, ret)
        else:
            # Add output rules and start a new row
            label = tree_.value[node]
            ret.append("return " + str(label[0][0]))
            row.append([])
    
    # Initialize
    rules = [[]]
    vals = []
    
    # Call recursive function with initial values
    recurse(0, rules, vals)
    
    # Convert to table and output
    df = pd.DataFrame(rules).dropna(how='all')
    df['Return'] = pd.Series(values)
    return df
```

Answer (score -1):

[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmsTm.png)

from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

from sklearn.tree import export_text

iris = load_iris()

X = iris['data']

y = iris['target']

decision_tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0, max_depth=2)

decision_tree = decision_tree.fit(X, y)

r = export_text(decision_tree, feature_names=iris['feature_names'])

print(r)

listt= [r]

print(listt)

#########OUTPUT###########################

|--- petal width (cm) <= 0.80

```
   |   |--- class: 0
```

|--- petal width (cm) >  0.80

```
   |   |--- petal width (cm) <= 1.75

       |   |   |--- class: 1
```

|   |--- petal width (cm) >  1.75

|   |   |--- class: 2

Comment: Can you please make the formatting more clear about which parts of the post are code and which parts are explanation?

Comment: sorry about that.

Comment: before this all is code 
#########OUTPUT###########################